# How to manage lost focus across a group of WinForms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to reliably detect when focus leaves a group of controls.  So if I tab or click between two controls in the group, that's considered not leaving, but as soon as I click on a control outside the group, it raises an event.  Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
public class LeaveTracker
{
    private HashSet<Control> trackedControls = new HashSet<Control>();
    public void Track(Control ctrl)
    {
        ctrl.Leave += Ctrl_Leave;
        trackedControls.Add(ctrl);
    }

    private void Ctrl_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var ctrl in trackedControls)
            if (ctrl.ContainsFocus)
                return;
        if (LeftControlGroup != null)
            LeftControlGroup(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler LeftControlGroup;
}
```

Sometimes it works perfectly, but occasionally it seems to stop raising events.  Is there a more reliable way to do this?

Comment: If you can place these controls on a panel, you can just use the `Leave` event of the panel instead.

Comment: Have you tried putting the sets of controls inside another custom User Control? I believe that User Control will have its own Leave event

Comment: There are other controls that are intermixed that aren't part of the group.

Comment: It's really hard to picture how that is supposed to work.  You have a screen shot of your form that shows these "groups"?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed This question is in no way a duplicate of the mouse leaving event.  This is about focus, not mouse pointer.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't see MouseHover anywhere in the referenced post.  I re-opened it since it's about leaving controls.  I'm still confused though.

Comment: @LarsTech That's focused on the MouseLeave event.  Like MouseEnter/MouseMove/MouseLeave are all mouse cursor position events, nothing to do with focus.

Comment: @LarsTech From the other question: _"The goal is when the user hoovers the mouse over the user control"_. I'd say the OP's question is very clear. He's trying to trigger an event whenever a group of _known_ controls (whatever they are) do not have focus.

Comment: The forms are pretty simple, a bunch of text boxes, comboboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes, etc.  I am porting an application written in MSAccess and trying to preserve the triggered behavior of when to save edited data.

Comment: Probably too many controls to see what is really going on.  Hard to see that the Leave event is not raised at the exact moment you hope.  It fires a bit too early, the control's ContainsFocus property is still true.  There is a simple and elegant fix, use this.BeginInvoke().  The invoked code runs right after the event, after the focus has changed.